# Nested Data inside output needing to be expanded

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = 'http://URL/api_jsonrpc.php' 

payload = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "event.get", "params": {"output": "extend", "selectAcknowledges": "extend", "selectTags": "extend", "selectSuppressionData": "extend", "selectHosts": ["hostid", "host", "name"], "recent": "true", "sortorder": "DESC"}, "auth": "XXX", "id": 1 }'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json-rpc'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, )
geteventlist = r.json()['result']

file = open('event.csv', 'w+', newline='', encoding="utf_8")

with file:

    header = ['hosts', 'host', 'hostid', 'location', 'eventid', 'userid', 'acknowledged', 'opdata', 'object', 'name', 'suppressed', 'c_eventid', 'clock', 'source', 'objectid', 'severity', 'urls', 'r_eventid', 'value', 'ns', 'suppression_data', 'correlationid', 'tags']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames = header)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(geteventlist)
```

This outputs the following type of data into a csv file. But I currently am running into an issue where the data outputs correctly bar one column where it has a nested java list which I cant seem to separate. Please see below the output in an excel format

[image: Output of script]

Basically looking for a way to expand this so I get 3 new columns of 'host' 'hostid' and 'name'.

I have tried the following solutions all with separate errors:

```
for hosts in geteventlist:
    hosts['host'] = hosts['hosts']['host']
    hosts['hostid'] = hosts['hosts']['hostid']
    hosts['name'] = hosts['hosts']['name']
    del hosts['hosts']
```

This outputs the following error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

I have also tried using the json_normalize function and that outputs the same error when confronted with 'hosts'

I have also tried to add a new dictionary by specifying the new dictionary with `mydict = {}`

But then this only captures the rows and not the data I need unless I am doing it incorrectly.

Does anyone have any information that would be beneficial for this?

Also to add the full output of the above code is the following

```
[{'eventid': '49', 'source': '0', 'object': '0', 'objectid': '22608', 'clock': '1648445474', 'value': '1', 'acknowledged': '0', 'ns': '948833226', 'name': 'Unavailable by ICMP ping', 'severity': '4', 'r_eventid': '89', 'c_eventid': '0', 'correlationid': '0', 'userid': '0', 'opdata': '', 'hosts': [{'hostid': '10519', 'host': 'Zabbix', 'name': 'Zabbix'}], 'suppression_data': [], 'suppressed': '0', 'urls': [], 'tags': [{'tag': 'scope', 'value': 'availability'}, {'tag': 'component', 'value': 'health'}, {'tag': 'component', 'value': 'network'}]}
```

What needs to be expanded is the nested list inside this which can be found after host:

`'hosts': [{'hostid': '10519', 'host': 'Zabbix', 'name': 'Zabbix'}]`

Comment: What is `print (geteventlist[:5])` ?

Comment: I can provide the output of this if still required

Comment: I've updated the OP with the full output of a single row (cant post 519 lines) and what in specific needs to be pulled out for each row

Comment: Can you try `df = pd.json_normalize(geteventlist, 'hosts')` ?

Comment: That separates the data that is required, how do I call that in my above script in my ```with file:``` section

When I just try and call that df it obviously gives me an unhashable type error when trying to put that data as well as the other data in a csv

Answer (score 1):

Building up on my comment : `geteventlist` looks like a list of list, with each nested list containing 1 dict.

In order to build a correct list :

```
csvList = []
for hosts in geteventlist:
    try:
        csvList.append({
            'host': hosts['hosts'][0]['host'],
            'hostid': hosts['hosts'][0]['hostid'],
            'name': hosts['hosts'][0]['name']
            }
        )
    except IndexError:
        print(f"List hosts at index {geteventlist.index(hosts)} is empty")
        continue

# Then writing the csv
with file:

    header = ['host', 'hostid', 'name']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames = header)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(csvList)
```

Output in the csv file with a list of 4 events :

```
host,hostid,name
Zabbix,10519,Zabbix
Zabbix,10519,Zabbix
Zabbix,10519,Zabbix
Zabbix,10519,Zabbix
```

Comment: Ran the above script and received the following error:  host': hosts[0]['host'], KeyError: 0

Comment: Sorry @Lachlan, I misunderstood the data structure, with the output you provided, I was able to understand it better and I modified the answer. Let me know if it works better.

Comment: I tried the updated version and now im getting list index out of range.

```IndexError: list index out of range```

Comment: I do not have your complete `geteventlist` unfortunately. Have you tried finding the problematics items with a debugger ? My guess is that some items are empty list, do you know how to surround the critical code with a `try/except` block in order to skip the empty lists ?

Comment: What information do you need about the list, most of the rows if not all are full of data. thre is about 1600 rows of data that need to be expanded so i can put it into a CSV. unfortunately no I dont know how to run a try/except block

Comment: Well, if the error is `IndexError: list index out of range` with index 0, that means the list is empty. I updated my answer with a block handling the exception. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: So that block has found 2 lists in the entire column that have no data, 225 and 1018.

```List hosts at index 225 is empty
List hosts at index 1018 is empty```

Comment: is there a way like how I can do in dataframes to drop empty lists? Can't seem to find a solution to get this to drop the rows so it can iterate through and expand the data as necessary.

Comment: This is what the code above is doing : each data is expanded in the variable `csvList`, when theres an empty list, `IndexError` is triggered and the keyword `continue` send the loop to the next iteration to continue the process. In the end, the csv should contains every non-empty row.

Comment: On my end the result is still nested. Hasn't been expanded. If I try and remove 'hosts' it gives me ```ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'hosts'```

Comment: Then I dont understand what you mean by nested, the output of the code above answer to your initial question, creating a csv with 3 different columns : hostid, host and name, with a row for each valid data in the initial list `geteventlist`. If you want to do something else, ask another question. Or update your question with your actual issue.

Comment: Well the output of the code is already posted in the initial question. The block of code above does output what rows are empty however when it gets moved into the CSV the the columns aren't seperated and still gets put into the csv under the header of 'hosts' and then all the nested columns are still inside that 'hosts' column.

Comment: @Lachlan, have you carefully change the last line ? the variable sent as parameter of the csv writter is different from yours since we create a new variable with a different structure than `geteventlist`. When running the above code, I get exactly what you expect as an output. See updated answer for a copy of the csv file.